# Migration from loop-aes to cryptsetup

Tags: partition, encryption

I've upgraded my linux installation to kernel 2.6.38-2 (Debian testing). With the new kernel, loop-aes does not compile, so I cannot mount my encrypted volumes. I heared that it is possible to use some compatibility mode of cryptsetup to mount encrypted volumes of loop-aes, so my question is:

How can I do that?

I have been searching for hours with Google and couldn't find anything that worked. With loop-aes, I was mounting partitions with the following entry in `/etc/fstab`:

```
/dev/sdb2 /mount/data   ext4 user,noauto,loop,encryption=aes256 0 0
```

How would the cryptsetup command line look like? I would prefer an fstab entry, if possible, but a command line would do as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cryptsetup loopaesOpen <device> <name> [--key-size 128] --key-file <key-file>`, according to http://code.google.com/p/cryptsetup/wiki/Cryptsetup130.  If your `cryptsetup` isn't 1.3.0, you're gonna have to download that version and compile it.

`cryptsetup` opens the volume and creates a new block device in `/dev/mapper/<name>`  You then have to use the `mount` command after `cryptsetup` to actually use it.

I know `crypttab` is involved in setting up boot-type encrypted volumes but I wrote my own scripts to manually mount them on demand so I have no experience with that, unfortunately.

Comment: I'll go test this one ASAP.

Comment: Well this one took some time, had to push it back in my work queue, but now I've migrated to `cryptsetup` (finally!) and it works as described. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `cryptsetup` edit `/etc/crypttab` and put in:

```
sdb2-data /dev/sdb2 none cipher=aes-cbc-plain,size=256,hash=sha512,noauto
```

Next edit `/etc/fstab` and add:

```
/dev/mapper/sdb2-data /mount/data ext4 user,noauto 0 0
```

Because you specified noauto you will need to run:

```
cryptdisks_start sdb2-data
mount /dev/mapper/sdb2-data
```

If you didn't have noauto then it would prompt for the password during bootup.