# Decrypting a previously create losetup device

Tags: linux, encryption, loop-device, cryptsetup

I've created an encrypted backup in 2004, using `losetup -e`. I still know the passphrase, so I should be fine, but losetup is gone in the linux distributions I use.

I still have a bash script for decryption, basically it reads

```
SEED="JMnvk8bp2y3P"
losetup -e aes128 -S "$SEED" -H sha256 "$LOOP" "$DATA"
mount -t ext2 "$LOOP" "$MOUNTPOINT"
```

While [`cryptsetup`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11902/migration-from-loop-aes-to-cryptsetup) is supposedly backwards-compatible, it doesn't support a cryptographic seed (losetup's `-S`).

Probably using an old bootable-CD linux distribution would help, **but how do I find one that supports `losetup -e`?** I can't download some five GB just to find out.

Comment: try sysresccd 2.4.1 - 3.0.0 (you can download old versions from their site)

Comment: Are you sure that wasn't a local or distribution-specific patch? None of the versions in Debian have ever mentioned `-S` in their man page or in their `--help` output.

Comment: An old bootable CD should only be around 650 MB, [Mint](http://www.linuxmint.com) & ubuntu live iso's are only 1 to 1.5GB, not 5GB

Comment: @Gilles, (I'm pretty sure I used some version of Debian to create it in the first place.) How did you search historical manpages?

Comment: @bayer I have a chroot with every version of Debian since slink. `zgrep -l -e -e /BIG/chroot/*/usr/{share/,}man/man8/losetup.8.gz` lists them all, but `zgrep -l -e -S /BIG/chroot/*/usr/{share/,}man/man8/losetup.8.gz` finds nothing. Nor does `zgrep seed /BIG/chroot/*/usr/{share/,}man/man8/losetup.8.gz`

Comment: Wow that's amazing. You did use `zgrep ... -- -S` or `'[-]S'` or similar? I have no idea why you wouldn't find it. I believe it's provided by a `loop-aes-utils" package.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get my `losetup -e`-style image file mounted with `cryptsetup`.

Formerly, I used

```
    losetup -e twofish /dev/loop0 disk-image-file.img
    mount -t ext3 /dev/loop0 /mnt/mount-point
```

I have replaced this with:

```
    cryptsetup -c twofish --type plain open disk-image-file.img the-disk
    mount -t ext3 /dev/mapper/the-disk /mnt/mount-point
```

Answer (score 0):

Following @frostschutz 's suggestion, I downloaded SystemRescueCd-x86-2.8.1 which includes a version of losetup that provides the `-S` seed argument. Thank y'all!